# Transforming differentials into Gaussian basis vector fields

Tags: general-relativity, vector-fields

I'm reading the following paper about black hole shadows **Black hole shadow in an expanding universe with a cosmological constant** (Perlick *et al*, 2018). In this paper, they define the following differentials

$$
d\tilde{t} = dt -\frac{H_0 r dr }{c^2 \sqrt{1- \frac{2m}{r}} \left( 1- \frac{2m}{r} - \frac{H_0^2 r^2}{c^2}\right)}  ,
$$

and,

$$
\frac{d\tilde{r}}{\tilde{r}} = \frac{\sqrt{1-\frac{2m}{r} dr}}{r\left( 1-\frac{2m}{r}-\frac{H_0^2 r^2}{c^2}\right)}  .
$$

In the following, they argue that these differentials are equivalent to the Gaussian basis vector field,

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \tilde{t}} = \frac{1-\frac{2m}{r}}{r\left( 1-\frac{2m}{r} -\frac{H_0^2 r^2}{c^2}\right)}\frac{\partial}{\partial t} + H_0 r\sqrt{1-\frac{2m}{r}}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}  ,
$$

and

$$
\tilde{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial \tilde{r}} = \frac{H_0 r^2}{c^2 \left( 1 - \frac{2m}{r} -\frac{H_0^2 r^2}{c^2}\right)}  \frac{\partial}{\partial t} + r \sqrt{1 - \frac{2m}{r}}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}  .
$$

My point here is how can we, starting from the differentials, arrive in the Gaussian basis vector field? Actually, I have no idea about how these steps are done, even though I'm looking at this problem for hours.

Any help would be appreciated,

Comment: If I understand correctly, you just need to invert the $2\times2$ Jacobian matrix to get the formula. Btw, it’s easier to use $\tilde r’=\ln \tilde r$

Comment: Actually, I did not understand... Is it just writing the first set of equations in matrix form and invert them?

Comment: For what its worth, I do not see those equations reducing to each other. I am curious what "equivalent" means in this context.

Comment: I understand equivalence in the sense that both set of equations yield the same transformations, but, I'm not sure....